# Conceptual meaning of nodes assignment in linked list

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures, linked-list

I am just wondering, in a linked list what is the difference between the two:

```
node1 = node2
```

and

```
node1->next = node2
```

The first line makes me a bit confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming from context here that `node1` and `node2` are pointers to nodes (for example, they might have a type like `Node *`). If that's not the case, please let me know!

If `node1` and `node2` are pointers, remember that there is a difference between *pointers to nodes* and *actual, honest-to-goodness node objects*. The pointers are just a way of saying "look over there and you'll find a node." The nodes themselves are actual objects containing data and links to other nodes.

For example, if you have two node pointers `node1` and `node2` that point to nodes, perhaps it looks like this:

```
+----------+              +----------+
|          | -----------> |  data!   |
+----------+              +----------+
    node1                 |  next!   | -----> ...
                          +----------+

+----------+              +----------+
|          | -----------> |  data!   |
+----------+              +----------+
    node2                 |  next!   | -----> ...
                          +----------+
```

If you write `node1->next = node2`, you're saying "follow the pointer named `node1` to see what node it points at, find the `next` pointer in that node, and change it to point to wherever `node2` points." That makes things look like this:

```
+----------+              +----------+
|          | -----------> |  data!   |
+----------+              +----------+
    node1                 |  next!   | -----> ...
                          +----------+
                               |
                               |
                               v
+----------+              +----------+
|          | -----------> |  data!   |
+----------+              +----------+
    node2                 |  next!   | -----> ...
                          +----------+
```

Writing `node1 = node2` means "change `node1` to point to whatever node `node2` is pointing at." That looks like this:

```
+----------+              +----------+
|          | ------+      |  data!   |
+----------+       |      +----------+
    node1          |      |  next!   | -----> ...
                   |      +----------+
                   |           |
                   |           |
                   |           v
+----------+       |      +----------+
|          | ------+----> |  data!   |
+----------+              +----------+
    node2                 |  next!   | -----> ...
                          +----------+
```

Fundamentally, there's no deep difference between these operations. They both change where some pointer is pointing. The difference is whether you're changing the `next` pointer inside of a node object or whether you're changing which node `node1` points at.

Whenever you have a question about what a line of code does that involves pointers or linked lists or the like, I highly recommend drawing pictures like the ones shown here. Building a visual intuition for what links you're creating and what links you're breaking is one of the best ways to better understand how code works. Plus, it's great for debugging!

Comment: Yes it is exactly the same case ! You are incredible. Thanks !